# ¿Cómo añadir imágenes dependiendo de una variable?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio en js en el cuál si en un input pongo un 5 o un 10 o un 50 me aparezca la imagen del billete correspondiente a ese número por pantalla pero no me muestra la imagen me sale un símbolo de imagen cortada que me indica que no carga bien la imagen pero la imagen está bien les paso mi código gracias.

Esto es lo que llevo hecho hasta el momento:

```js
function billete() {

  let billete1 = document.getElementById('billete1').value;



  switch (billete1) {

    case "5":
      let result5 = "existe";
      document.getElementById('existe').innerText = result5;
      document.getElementById("imagen").innerHTML = '<img src="assents\img\B10.jpg" />';
      break;

    case "10":
      let result = "existe";
      document.getElementById('existe').innerText = result;
      //const img = document.createElement("img");
      //img.src = "assents\img\B10.jpg";
      //document.body.appendChild(img).innerHTML = imagen;
      document.getElementById("imagen").innerHTML = '<img src="assents\img\B10.jpg" />';
      break;

    case "20":
      let result2 = "existe";
      document.getElementById('existe').innerText = result2;
      break;

    case "50":
      let result55 = "existe";
      document.getElementById('existe').innerText = result55;
      break;

    case "100":
      let result10 = "existe";
      document.getElementById('existe').innerText = result10;
      break;

    case "200":
      let result20 = "existe";
      document.getElementById('existe').innerText = result20;
      break;

    case "500":
      let result50 = "existe";
      document.getElementById('existe').innerText = result50;
      break;
    default:
      let nada = "no existe el billete, intente otro"
      document.getElementById('existe').innerText = nada;
      break;
  }

}
```

```html
<h1>comprueba los billetes</h1>
<label for="billete1"></label><input type="number" id="billete1" /><br>
<input type="button" onClick="billete()" value="billete" />
<p><br>
  <span id="existe"></span>
  <div id="imagen"></div>
</p>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Por favor, no uses las respuestas para agregar código. Pulsa sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece en el pie de tu pregunta para agregarlo en su lugar. Cuando lo hayas hecho elimina esa no-respuesta. Las preguntas han de ser autocontenidas y no esparcidas entre comentarios y respuestas. Lecturas recomendadas: [ask], [tour] y [example]. Gracias por tu colaboración. Si lo haces obtendrás mejores respuestas.

Comment: Diría que estás equivocándote en dos cosas, ambos errores tipográficos. Estás poniendo rutas así:  `assents\img\B10.jpg` cuando lo normal es 1) que la carpeta se llame `asserts` (revisa bien el nombre) y 2) que las barras de las rutas no son invertidas (\\) en html, sino normales (`/`)... por lo tanto la ruta correcta, si verificas bien el nombre de la carpeta, sería esta: `asserts/img/B10.jpg`.  Prueba de cambiarlos todos y nos cuentas si con eso ya está arreglado.

Comment: Como dice @masterguru, el erro debe estar en la ruta de la imagen. He ejecutado tu código con imágenes de internet y el código funciona perfectamente, así que el error seguramente está en lo mencionado por el autor en el comentario anterior.